# how to fix one side of artboard get blurry in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, artboard

I don't why one side of the art board getting blurry. As I'm hovering the mouse cursor on the element, it getting more and more blurry and falling downward like fluid, funny but what is problem and how to fix it? Please help me, thanks in advance. [image: image of blurry problem]

Here I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: Try to disable GPU rendering: `Window > CPU view`... Or something like that. It should be the first item in the menu. If it says "whatever... GPU", then you already had CPU preview on. Or see if restarting the computer deals with it.

Comment: @Joonas Thank you so much <3. It's now OK.